# Make string literals contains newline symbol automatically?

Tags: c, string, macros, literals

I use to define multi-line stuff, something like a help message, like this:

```
#define HELP_MSG "blabla\r\n" \
                 "Some other line"
```

Is there a way that I can avoid putting "\r\n" here, since I already have it defined in multiple line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `\` is merely used as a line *continuation* marker. If you need a line break, you need to include it explicitly in the string, as you're doing.